# gRPC request showing cancelled code for localhost

Tags: spring-boot, grpc

I'm testing a gRPC service. With 'grpc.postman-echo.com' the service shows correct output. But when is tested with the normal gRPC request, it does not get executed and returns 'Operation cancelled. You have cancelled the execution of the method'. What is going wrong here?

The proto file is

```
yntax = "proto3";
option java_multiple_files = true;
option java_package = "com.example.grpc";
option java_outer_classname = "HelloServiceProto";
service HelloService {
    rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloResponse) {}
}

message HelloRequest {
    string name = 1;
}

message HelloResponse {
    string message = 1;
}
```

service code is

```
import io.grpc.Status;
import io.grpc.stub.StreamObserver;

public class HelloServiceImpl extends HelloServiceGrpc.HelloServiceImplBase {

    @Override
    public void sayHello(HelloRequest request, StreamObserver<HelloResponse> responseObserver) {
        try{
        String name = request.getName();
        String message = "Hello, " + name + "!";
        HelloResponse response = HelloResponse.newBuilder().setMessage(message).build();
        responseObserver.onNext(response);
        responseObserver.onCompleted();
        }catch(io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException e){
            Status status = io.grpc.Status.fromThrowable(e);
            System.out.println("Status: " + status);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try to enable TLS in postman when you send the request.

[See postman documentation for how to toggle TLS](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/grpc/grpc-request-interface/#the-request-section)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).